# SAS Proc tabulate- percentage for distinct persons

Tags: sas, percentage

let's say I have the following dataset:

```
data meal;
    input PERSON_ID FOOD $;
    datalines;
    1 EGGS
    2 APPLES
    3 BACON
    4 EGGS
    4 APPLES
    ;
run;
```

When using proc tabulate in the following way:

```
proc tabulate data=meal;
    class FOOD;
    table (FOOD='' all="Number of Meals"),(N pctn);
quit;
```

I get the number and percentages of the meals based on the total number of meals (N=5).

Is there any simple way in proc tabulate to calculate the percentage based on the number of different PERSON_IDs (N=4)? I basically want to get from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no way to calculate unique counts within PROC TABULATE. You can either consider adding an indicator variable to indicate the first person record and then summarize using that variable or you can pre calculate your results and use PROC PRINT or REPORT to display the data.

Comment: If you want to make a suggestion for a change/feature, you can go to communities.sas.com and add it to the SAS Ballotware list.